# How to rename the files in same location in Ni-Fi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some files in my sftp path and i want to rename the files in same location using Ni-Fi.

Please suggest any procesor in nifi which is suitable for my case.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please provide more info. Do you want to rename them in a certain pattern? do you get the new names from somewhere? do you want to change their names from `X` to `X_Y`?

Comment: First thanks for your response.I have a file with the in /tmp/a.csv.gz format and i want convert that file to orc format and load to hdfs and till this it's working fine

Comment: once the above process is completed finally i want to move the files to file  to tmp/loaded/a.csv.gz.done

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UpdateAtrribute` Processor : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html

and update the value of : `${filename}`

Comment: I tried this one it's not working in my case and I used fetchsftp to fetch the file and used update attribute to update the filename with.done after that i used putsftp to drop the files but its not working

Comment: did you use the CompressContent Processor ? it can rename your zip sometime.
can you post a picture of your flow ?

Comment: My process is working fine i have problems with renaming the files after my process

Comment: Now i want to rename files from /tmp/test.csv to /tmp/loaded/test.csv.done